When to use SOFR strip VS Eris interest rate swap, what is the difference?
I am a beginner in financial risk management. learning this as a hobby. Please guide me here.
Here we have 2 examples where one example uses ERIS swap futures and other uses SOFR strip to hedge.
What is the difference ? how to know which one to use ?
CASE 1:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMdj_eJQyDA&t=28s
10 million loan for 5 years
sell 100 YIW eris swap future contracts.
Is it same as Sell 10 contracts of SOFR for each quarter (except the current one) for the next 5 years ?
Total of selling 190 SOFR contracts (10*4*4+10*3).
CASE 2:
https://www.cmegroup.com/education/courses/introduction-to-sofr/understanding-sofr-strips.html
100 million 2 year loan.
Sell 100 contracts of SOFR for each quarter (except the current one)
Total of selling 700 SOFR contracts.
Is it same as selling 1000 2 year Eris SWAP futures ?
Thank you.

The 3 alternatives are (1) OTC interest rate swap with a Bank, (2) Strip of i.r. futures traded on a futures exchange (3) a relatively new product Eris swap futures, which is similar to (1) in how it works but has been designed to trade on a futures exchange
https://www.marketswiki.com/wiki/Eris_Exchange . (1) is probably the most used, followed by (2) and (3) has not come into much use yet AFAIK, since it is so new. https://www.erisfutures.com/cme/volumeopeninterest

Look at it from the point of view of the real estate developer in the CME infomercial. He already has relationships with banks (one of which gave him a loan), they will be glad to offer him a swap or other bank product like FRA to manage this risk. He probably has never traded futures, may not have a futures account, and may not even have heard of Eris Futures yet. So the CME faces a hurdle in entering this bank dominated business.
